# Foundation Abide in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, zurb-foundation, abide

Creating a form in cakephp so it works with Foundation abide.

```
<form data-abide>
```

I need the echoed form HTML in CakePHP to add data-abide to the attribute form without class or div.

I have no idea how I'm meant to do this google and the Docs on Cake have been no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->create('Model', array('data-abide'));
```

This will generate something like

```
<form action="" data-abide="data-abide" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Does that work?